# Cool Infobox and plot polygons through xml ....in bing maps , pure javascript

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

I have just started with bing maps and wish to accompilish two things for my project .
a) define layers/shapes by loading data via xml
B) Have a tooltip/infobox like this  [site](http://www.zillow.com/homes/for_sale/#/homes/for_sale/54.103489,-55.806097,31.567703,-146.15766_rect/3_zm/):-

[check the source file here](http://pastebin.com/KtJTcYZB)

Comment: ok... so what's stopping you? There's no question here.

Comment: sorry , if I have not phrased it well. I wish to know how we can have a tooltip as in the link, and how we can to hav the shapes defined ny xml data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For custom infoboxes in Bing Maps there are two options. The first is to use the built in infobox control and set the html content property. I have a blog post on how to do this here: http://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2011/11/08/simple-custom-infoboxes-in-bing-maps-v7/

The second method is to use the custom infobox module I created for Bing Maps V7 here: http://bingmapsv7modules.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom%20Infobox%20Control

Answer (score 0):

As for XML data, if it is in GeoRSS or GML format then you can use this module:
http://bingmapsv7modules.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=GeoRSS%20Plugin

If it is in GPX format you can use this module:
http://bingmapsv7modules.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=GPX%20Parser

Answer (score 0):

For tooltips you can take a look at this blog post: http://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2011/11/21/pushpin-tooltips-in-bing-maps-v7/