# Issue in infobox repositioning in Bing map v7

Tags: javascript, asp.net, bing-maps

I am using the Bing map version 7 for the displaying the events and its details on map. For that i have added the following reference js file "http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0&mkt=de"

I have implemented the displaying the event pin on map and displaying the event details in infobox. I am stuck up with displaying event details in infobox which are on the boundary of the map. This infobox goes outside the map.

I have found on solution in the post
[Cool Infobox and plot polygons through xml ....in bing maps , pure javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9269455/cool-infobox-and-plot-polygons-through-xml-in-bing-maps-pure-javascript)

But even after implementing the solution mentioned(CustomInfoboxModule) in above link, i am facing the issue for the events having more details.

Check for the [image]

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure if I understand the question. Is your issue that the infobox falls outside of the map? If so, if you make your Infobox big enough this is bound to happen. There are a couple of solutions:

1. Limit the size of your description area (i.e. give it a max-height) and make it scrollable (i.e. overflow-y: auto). This will ensure that your infobox never exceeds a certain height. The custom infobox control you are using, positions the infobox based on which quadrant the pushpin is in. If the pushpin is in the top left corner the infobox is shown to the right and down. If the pushpin is in the bottom right corner the infobox is shown to the left and up. This means that if you ensure that the max height of the infobox is half the height of the map, that it should always be displayed within the map.
2. Alternatively, if you know the infobox will never be bigger than the height of the map, you could simply reposition the map so that the pushpin is higher and then open the infobox.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Your understanding is correct  infobox falls outside the map if it contains the more details. I have already tried for the both solution you have mentioned above. Issues i am facing with this solution1 is if the height of infobox is grater than the half of the map the infobox falls outside as shown in image above. The issue with solution2 is after repositioning the map the other pins location, bounds of the map also gets affected, causing the the some pins goes outside the map bounds.

Comment: Also i have checked the this issue with old bing map version where infoox repositioning is automatically managed. This means that this issue is present in bing map version 7 only. is there any other alternatives for this issue in bing map v7?

Comment: The V7 control is the old version of Bing Maps. It's over 6 years old and was actually recently replaced by version 8 which handles infoboxes in the same way. It sounds like you might be referring to the v6.3 control which will is deprecated and will be turned off in November. The custom infobox control you are using in V7 was built for those who wanted to maintain the functionality that was in v6.3.